# my terminal is not recognizing my flask command after i installed flask

Tags: bash, terminal, python, environment-variables, package-management

I ran into a problem with the terminal, it didn't recognize my flask command!
the whole issue started with

```
WARNING: The script isort is installed in '/Users/bigdad/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

so I added the path "/Users/bigdad/Library/Python/3.8/bin" to my local variables using nano `sudo nano /etc/paths` command and add it.

It didn't work, so I tried another method export `PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/bigdad/Library/Python/3.8/bin`, and it still didn't work

[This is what i'm stuck with now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O9vy.png)

can any one guid me please?

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me when i added the path `/Users/bigdad/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages`

to my environment using `sudo nano /etc/paths`